# No Suitable Conversion Function from LoadTask::MasterFilePtr to MasterFile * exists

Tags: c++, pointers, types

I am new to C++ and am having some trouble understanding some conversion behavior.

In `LoadTask.h` I type define `MasterFilePtr`:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<MasterFile> MasterFilePtr;
```

I then initialize the `masterFile` variable:

```
MasterFilePtr masterFile;
```

Later, in `LoadTask.cpp` I pass `masterFile` as a parameter to a function:

```
dataLoader.SetMasterFile( masterFile  );
```

where the function is defined as:

```
void SetMasterFile( MasterFile * pMasterFile ) { m_pMasterFile = pMasterFile; };
```

---

Passing in `masterFile` causes issues though, and I receive an error:

> No Suitable Conversion Function from `LoadTask::MasterFilePtr` to `MasterFile *` exists

I thought that the `typedef` set `MasterFilePtr` to be equivalent to `MasterFile *`, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Furthermore, I was able to get past the error by trying:

```
dataLoader.SetMasterFile( &*masterFile  );
```

This feels very wrong though, so can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: `shared_ptr` is a wrapper class for a raw (naked) pointer. Your function expects a raw pointer, not that wrapper class. Cleanest way is probably to get the original pointer with `get()` (although you lose the benefits of reference counting and automatic memory management - i.e. what `shared_ptr` is all about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadTask::MasterFilePtr` is an alias for `std::shared_ptr<MasterFile>`. You cannot pass `shared_ptr` to a function that expects raw pointer - there is no implicit conversion defined. In order to extract raw pointer from `shared_ptr` you need to use either `get()` method or use the trick you discovered.